# if (boolean condition) in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

This is always very confusing to me. Can someone please explain it? The confusion I have is - boolean default to false. So in the below example, does it enter the `if` loop when state is not turned on, i.e., it is TURNED OFF `if (condition is false)` **OR** does it enter the `if` loop when state is TURNED ON, in other words `if (condition is true)`?

```
boolean turnedOn;
if (turnedOn) {
    //do stuff when the condition is false or true?
} else {
    //do else of if
}
```

I know this is a very basic question, but if you could explain the answer in very basic language, that would be great. :) Feel free to point me to duplicate posts that have a very good explanation (I did not find one where I could clearly get it). Also feel free to change the subject of the post if you'd like to make it more generic.

Comment: Does this compile: boolean state = "TURNED ON"; ??

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Okay, so..

```
// As you already stated, you know that a boolean defaults to false.
boolean turnedOn;
if(turnedOn) // Here, you are saying "if turnedOn (is true, that's implicit)
{
//then do this
}
else // if it is NOT true (it is false)
{
//do this
}
```

Does it make more sense now?

The `if` statement will evaluate whatever code you put in it that returns a boolean value, and if the evaluation returns true, you enter the first block. **Else** (if the value is **not** true, it will be false, because a boolean can either be true or false) it will enter the - yep, you guessed it - the `else {}` block.

A more verbose example.

If I am asked "are you hungry?", the simple answer is yes (true). or no (false).

```
boolean isHungry = true; // I am always hungry dammit.
if(isHungry) { // Yes, I am hungry.
   // Well, you should go grab a bite to eat then!
} else { // No, not really.
   // Ah, good for you. More food for me!

   // As if this would ever happen - bad example, sorry. ;)
}
```

Comment: What if turnedOn is actually false. Lets say in my above code, I had something like - boolean turnedOn=false, and then rest of the code was the same, then?

Comment: Can someone please answer this?

Comment: Then it would enter the `else` block, as stated. In an `if` statement, you implicitly ask if turnedOn is true - you could also do `if(turnedOn == false)`, then you would enter the first block (because when turnedOn is false, then turnedOn == false is true).

Comment: @rickygrimes Great, glad I could help. Going for a snack, brb.

Answer (score 14):

In your example, the IF statement will run when it is state = true meaning the else part will run when state = false.

```
if(turnedOn == true) is the same as if(turnedOn)

if(turnedOn == false) is the same as if(!turnedOn)
```

If you have:

```
boolean turnedOn = false;
```

Or

```
boolean turnedOn;
```

Then

```
if(turnedOn)
{

}
else
{
    // This would run!
}
```

Answer (score 4):

ABoolean (with a uppercase 'B') is a Boolean object, which if not assigned a value, will default to null. boolean (with a lowercase 'b') is a boolean primitive, which if not assigned a value, will default to false.

```
Boolean objectBoolean;
boolean primitiveBoolean;

System.out.println(objectBoolean); // will print 'null'
System.out.println(primitiveBoolean); // will print 'false'
```

[Citation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152656/ifboolean-condition-in-java/19152785#19152785)

so in your code because boolean with small 'b' is declared it will set to false hence

```
boolean turnedOn;
    if(turnedOn) **meaning true**
    {
    //do stuff when the condition is false or true?
    }
    else
    {
    //do else of if ** itwill do this part bechae it is false
    }
```

the if(turnedon) tests a value if true, you didnt assign a value for turned on making it false, making it do the else statement :)

Comment: @Jeff yes it is but no one noticed it.

Comment: Which is too bad, really.

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean state = "TURNED ON";
```

is not a Java valid code. boolean can receive only boolean values (true or false) and `"TURNED ON"`is a String.

**EDIT**:

now you are talking about a loop and your code does not contain any. your var `state` is false because the boolean default value and you execute the else clause.

Comment: Sorry about that. In my application, the parameter TURNED ON is set to false through property files. I copied pasted it from the code. I just edited it. Thanks for letting me know so it doesn't confuse other readers of the post.

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean turnedOn;
    if(turnedOn)
    {
    //do stuff when the condition is true - i.e, turnedOn is true
    }
    else
    {
    //do stuff when the condition is false - i.e, turnedOn is false
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to check a boolean. If true, do something. Else, do something else. You can write:

```
if(condition==true){

}
else{   //else means this checks for the opposite of what you checked at if

}
```

instead of that, you can do it simply like:

```
if(condition){  //this will check if condition is true 

}
else{ 

}
```

Inversely. If you were to do something if condition was false and do something else if condition was true. Then you would write:

```
if(condition!=true){   //if(condition=false)

}
else{

}
```

But following the simple path. We do:

```
if(!condition){  //it reads out as: if condition is not true. Which means if condition is false right?

}
else{
```

}

Think about it. You'll get it in no time.

Answer (score 0):

Booleans default value is false only for classes' fields. If within a method, you have to initialize your variable by true or false. Thus for example in your case, you'll have a compilation error.

Moreover, I don't really get the point, but the only way to enter within a if is to evaluate the condition to true.

Comment: boolean field with a lowercase b will have a default value of false. A Boolean field with a upercase B will have a default value of null.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `state` is having a valid boolean value set in your actual code, then the following condition will succeed

```
if(state)
```

when state is boolean value is TRUE

If condition checks for the expression whether it is evaluated to TRUE/FALSE. If the expression is simple `true` then the condition will succeed.

Comment: What do you mean by valid boolean? Does it enter if loop if state is true, or when it is false?

Comment: @rickygrimes i already have a comment on the question for the same. The valid value for a boolean is true or false. And you have mentioned in your sample "TURNED ON"

Answer (score 0):

This is how the `if` behaves.

```
if(turnedOn) // This turnedOn should be a boolean or you could have a condition here which would give a boolean result.
{
// It will come here if turnedOn is true (i.e) the condition in the "if" evaluates to true
}
else
{
// It will come here if turnedOn is false (i.e) the condition in the "if" evaluates to false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (turnedOn) {
    //do stuff when the condition is false or true?
}
else {
    //do else of if
}
```

It can be written like:

```
if (turnedOn == true) {
        //do stuff when the condition is false or true?
    }
else { // turnedOn == false or !turnedOn
        //do else of if
}
```

So if your `turnedOn` variable is true, **if** will be called, if is assigned to false, **else** will be called. boolean values are implicitly assigned to false if you won't assign them explicitly e.q. `turnedOn = true`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of if block is as below,

```
if(condition){
// Executes when condition evaluates to true.
}
else{
// Executes when condition evaluates to false.
}
```

In your case you are directly passing a boolean value so no evaluation is required.

Answer (score 0):

Every time the condition "**if (turnedOn)**", always refers as "**TRUE condition**", unless the condition is "***if (!turnedOn)***" will refer as "***FALSE condition***".

In other case, if you want to compare two Boolean condition, for example;

Two boolean variable: **turnedOn**, **switchedOn**

Let's say current condition;

turnedOn=true
switchedOn=false

- "**if (turnedOn) || if (switchedOn)**" will return **TRUE**
- "**if (turnedOn) && if (switchedOn)**" will return **FALSE**